# What is the meaning of 'collection' attribute in Backbone Model?

Tags: backbone.js

A Backbone.Model object maintains a 'collection' attribute.
In the Backbone source code, we have :

```
var Model = Backbone.Model = function(attributes, options) {
   ...    
   if (options && options.collection) this.collection = options.collection;
   ...
}
```

The [annotated source](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/docs/backbone.html) says nothing about that, and the [documentation](http://backbonejs.org/#Model) references only functions.
I guess it's mainly used when deleting the model : the collection removes this model.

But what if the model belongs to many collections ? Is there a danger to use/override this collection attribute ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's used in two places (look a bit further down in the annotated source).

- As you note, it's used when a model is destroyed, to remove the model from the collection.

> Optimistically removes the model from its collection, if it has one.

- In the `url` function, if the collection exists with a URL scheme, it uses that to construct a URL for the model.

> if you're using Backbone's restful methods, override this to change the endpoint that will be called.